# How to generate a git patch with a local commit

Tags: git

I'm contributing to the development of an open source project which use a git as a repository for the source code.

After do some modification on the source code I want to generate a patch containig my signature (email address and My name) and send it to the open source project maintainer.

How  can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Download source code from the git repository:

```
git clone git://address.of.repository/project/ /folder/path/on/my/computer
```

2) Do some modification on the source code. a new files/folders could be added in the project

3) set your email address and your name for the git commit signature:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

4) Before commit the changes. we have to add the new files/folders to the local git repository:

under the project folder of the source code

```
git add <Newfolder>
git add <Newfile>
```

4) And then commit locally the modification with:

under the project folder of the source code

```
commit -a
```

this will open an interactif window

you can check that commit has detected the edited files and the new files under:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   bin/Makefile.am
#       modified:   configure.ac
#       new file:   src/new.c
```

under the window of `commit -a`, you have to enter comment for your modifications

and then save your commit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> ( WriteOut) and then `Enter` and your commit is become saved now

and then quit the `commit -a` window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (Exit)

5) now you can generate your patch with:

under the project folder of the source code

```
git format-patch -1
```

this will generate a patch file with a name like `0001-...-...-.. .patch`

If you want to generate patch with `signed-off-by` just add `-s`:

```
git format-patch -1 -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: regarding the `git format-patch` part, you will (git 2.0.x/git 2.11, Q3 2014) add a signature defined in a file.

See [commit 7022650](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7022650f61ff7d7c9297db4a04f4e93ae14e1750) by [Jeremiah Mahler (`jmahler`)](https://github.com/jmahler)

#### `format-patch`: add "`--signature-file=<file>`" option

> Add an option to format-patch for reading a signature from a file.

```
$ git format-patch -1 --signature-file=$HOME/.signature
```

> The config variable `format.signaturefile` can also be used to make this the default.

```
$ git config format.signaturefile $HOME/.signature
$ git format-patch -1
```